# Using volley to populate a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-volley

I am working on a simple app and I am having issues understanding how to use volley for something I feel should be an easy task. Currently I have gotten volley to grab a json array that populates a list of images with titles next to them. The problem is I want to be able to press on an item in the list and spawn a new fragment with a larger version of the image in it. This seems like a really basic task, but I can't seem to find the right way to do it. If I grab the full images to create the list view, I run out of memory. I started grabbing thumbnail images, but then when I create the fragment, the view is inflated before the request for the image finishes. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a placeholder image while Volley downloads your image, and an error image if the download wasn’t successful. In your situation, you can use your thumbnail image as the placeholder image.

The **Making Image Request** section in this [artcle](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/) shows the good way to handle image request with Volley.

Sample code:

```
// Loading image with placeholder and error image
imageLoader.get(Const.URL_IMAGE, ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                imageView, YOUR_THUNMBNAIL_IMAGE, R.drawable.ico_error));
```

Comment: So that makes sense, part of the issue is that I am grabbing the image from a JSON api that has the image encoded as a base64 string, rather then downloading a bitmap. Can I still use the imageLoader?

Comment: imageLoader is to download image from a URL, so imageLoader will not be useful. But you can still set a place holder image before you finish setting up your large image.